# How to hide/unhide clear icon from textbox in sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to hide clear icon from textbox in sencha control through code.
How to do it? 
Please provide sample code.

Thanks

Comment: Try the clearIcon config of textfield.

Comment: You don't need to define it in through CSS. Setting `clearIcon:false` on field will do it.

Comment: 'through code' I read 'dynamically' but if it was not the case then clearIcon: false is the solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this ::

```
{
    xtype : 'textfield',
    clearIcon : false,
    name : 'name',
    id : 'whatever'
}
```

There's a config property called `clearIcon` that you can toggle.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to you global CSS

```
.x-field-clearable.clear-icon-hidden .x-field-input .x-clear-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

and then when you want to hide the clear icon of a field you just get your field and do

```
field.addCls('clear-icon-hidden');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: not working.. I also used setClearIcon method to set 'true' and 'false' but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the clearIcon config to false. Like this,

`Ext.getCmp('ID OF THE TEXTFIELD').setClearIcon(false)`;

Example:

```
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'MyFieldSet',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id: 'textfield1',
                    label: ''
                },
```

Solution:

```
Ext.getCmp('textfield1').setClearIcon(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what version of Ext JS this was pertaining to, here is an update for Ext JS 6.5.x as it no longer uses clearIcon.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    itemId: 'tfLastName',
    label: 'Last Name',
    value: 'Allord',
    *clearable: false*,
    editable: false
},
```

This is also for the [modern toolkit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.field.Text.html#cfg-clearable), per Sencha documentation; the classic toolkit doesn't have this feature.